# ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Api: POST with unknown or not specified Content-Type

Tags: http-post, asp.net-mvc-4, content-type

My web api returns the error code **500**, if a client POST's some data and not specifying the content-type.

The Error-Message

> No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type
>   'Document' from content with media type ''undefined''.

show that the server can't find a formatter.

But in this case: "no content-typ or unknown content-type set by the client", the client is responsible for the error - not the server.
Instead of an error code 500, the web api should return somthing like **4XX**.

My question is: How can I configure the web api that it will return a status code 400.

An other exapmle is: While content negotiation: If The client sends that he accept XML, but the server cant send XML but JSON, the server sends JSON anyway. In this case the web api should return the status code: 406 Not Acceptable.

Comment: Alright but what is your question? Did you open a ticket on MS Connect? I would recommend you to hurry up before it hits RTM.

Comment: Are running the beta or the RC?

Comment: I'm running the RC version. My question is: How can I influence the returncodes in this case(s).

Comment: I did not found a product for that on MS Connect.

Comment: [ASP.Net web api updates May 14](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/05/14/asp-net-web-api-updates-may-14.aspx) talks about taking over content negotiation from the default. A search for ASP.Net web api 406 will find you blog posts about implementing the 406 response for earlier versions